# Storing cache using .manifest file doesn't work

Tags: caching, ipad, web-applications

I'm currently developing a Web app for the iPad.
So I created the whole "application", with my different html files, my css, my pictures.
Now the next step for me is to be able to cache the files to use the "application" offline.
I follow the advices I found on different websites, with the manifest file and everything.
It seems I'm the only one with this issue, because I searched on Internet an answer to my issue, but I didn't find anything.

So I created my manifest file (ipad.manifest) which looks like this :

```
    $CACHE MANIFEST

    $/WebApp/home-start.htm
    $/WebApp/accommodation.htm
    $/WebApp/accommodation2.htm
    $/WebApp/dining.htm
    $/WebApp/entertainment.htm
    $/WebApp/general.htm
    $/WebApp/home.htm
    $/WebApp/shopping.htm
    $/WebApp/sights.htm
    $/WebApp/sports.htm
    $/WebApp/css/screen3.css
    $/WebApp/Player/CanalVenetian.mp4
    $/WebApp/Player/DancingWater.mp4
    $/WebApp/Player/NaCha.mp4
    $/WebApp/Player/NaCha2.mp4
    $/WebApp/Player/Opening.mp4
    $/WebApp/Player/previewhome.jpg
    $/WebApp/Player/previewsights.jpg
    $/WebApp/Player/previewvenetian.jpg
    $/WebApp/Player/Venetian.mp4
    $/WebApp/Player/video.js
    $/WebApp/Player/Zaia.mp4
    $/WebApp/iPad/startup.png
    $/WebApp/iPad/pixel.gif
    $/WebApp/iPad/asktt-ipad-accommodation2.jpg
    $/WebApp/iPad/asktt-ipad-camera.jpg
    $....
```

I tried with both, relative and absolute links, and it's still not working.

And in every html files I added :

```
    $<!DOCTYPE html>
    $<html manifest="ipad.manifest">
    $<head>
```

When I go to the website with the iPad and click on "add to home screen", it adds the icon on the home screen but didn't download the content. So each time I open the application it starts to load everything....

When I tried on desktop browsers it didn't ask me to cache the content on my computer.

I added an header "content/type : text/manifest" for my mime type files on my server.

But I don't understand why it doesn't cache anything, or doesn't even ask me if I want to cache the files???

Does someone have an idea ? Or had the same issue ?

Answer (score 0):

try with this, put it on the root of your app and name it manifest.php and add it to your html web app with

php file start here

```
$hashes="";

$dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(".");
foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir) as $file){
    if ($file->IsFile() &&
        $file != "./manifest.php" &&
        substr($file->getFilename(),0,1) != ".")
    {
    echo $file . "\n";
    $hashes .= md5_file($file);        
    }
}
echo "# Hash:" . md5($hashes) . "\n";
```

?>
php file ends here